# Set start date to beginning of the year and end date to one day prior to current date

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to set startdate and enddate in python but ran across some problem. What i want is start date set to beginning of the year and enddate set to one day prior to current date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time,date

my_str= '2020-01-01'
stdate= datetime.strptime(my_str,'%Y-%m-%d')
print(stdate)
edate = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)
print(edate)
```

Right now the output is date with time.But i only want to output date not time

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-03-01 12:25:50.542813
```

Comment: Sorry, should read: `print(edate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`. Read up on [datetime.datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start_of_current_year = date(date.today().year, 1, 1)
end_of_previous_year = start_of_current_year - timedelta(days=1)

# Check values
print(start_of_current_year)
print(end_of_previous_year)
```